# Windows VLAN Tagging Network Adapter

Tags: windows-10, vlan, pfsense

I am trying to add VLAN tagging to my INTEL Nic in windows 10 and having some trouble.  I have been following the guide [here](http://woshub.com/configure-multiple-vlan-on-windows/#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20the%20VLAN%20section,from%20the%20corresponding%20IP%20subnet.) and it works for the most part.  The problem is that is creates a new network adapter with the correct VLAN tag but continues to use both network adapters.  I know this is happening because I can view my pfsense firewall logs and see that traffic is trying to get through both VLANs.  One of the vlans is connect to a VPN so I do not want this happening.  I want all traffic coming out of the PC to be tagged with the correct VLAN.  This used to work perfectly but windows has done so many changes to make VLAN tagging nearly impossible.  Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

When I did something similar to this, I made sure to not assign an IP to the parent interface. Some NIC drivers might already do this by default.

The parent interface can be used for untagged traffic, which you wish to avoid and all the child interfaces then carry only tagged traffic. It should no longer be able to send untagged traffic.

[image: network interface/properties/]